# PHP cannot access cookies that were set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Here's the JavaScript code setting cookies:

```
<script>
  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
  }
  setCookie("_ga_cid", '111', 30);
</script>
```

Here's the PHP code that runs on the same domain called via Ajax:

```
$ga_client_id = (isset($_COOKIE['_ga_cid']))? $_COOKIE['_ga_cid'] : '[empty]';
```

For some reason `$ga_client_id` is always `'[empty]'`, even though the code before should have initialized it. Why is it `'[empty]'`?

The PHP script is called using Ajax, so by the time it is being run the cookie should be accessible on the server.

Comment: and how is this cookie travelling from the browser to the server?

Comment: The PHP script is called using Ajax, so by the time it is being run the cookie should be accessible on the server.

Comment: `Here's the PHP code that runs on the same domain right after JavaScript above:` - no evidence of any AJAX

Comment: Edited the question, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: JS will set cookies on client machine. A server app cannot access client internal data unless it is clearly allowed to.

Comment: @AlanMachado — The entire point of cookies is that they are sent to the server! It isn't possible to set cookies without the server having access to them.

Comment: check the Developer Tools network tab, see what cookies are being sent in the AJAX request

Comment: Request headers from Developer Tools show that _ga_cid cookie is being sent to the server.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAM6emlQVSlOO6ViJmw_tdyXn5VG1d5ZJro) and [code](http://jsbin.com/rodubi/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: @Sergey — Then $_COOKIE should be populated normally.

Comment: Hm, I guess the problem is in the PHP code...

Comment: The line of PHP works fine when I try a local test too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was a proxy script that called the PHP script I attached to the question. This proxy used file_get_contents and the cookie header was lost.
Thanks everyone who commented for help!